# ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know that this error exist in many posts but I tried everything without any solution. After I changed the value model in the auth.php file, to the correct path of the user model, my controllers are not working. All of the controllers throwing the following issue but only the Auth controller is working fine. The error message that I'm getting is:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class
>   APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController does not exist

I made composer dump-autoload but still the same. My controller is inside App\Http\Controllers\Administrator\Dashboard\DashboardController.php

```
namespace APPPATH\Http\Controllers;

    class DashboardController extends Controller {}
```

and inside my route i have this

```
get('/', array('as' => 'administrator.dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));

get('/dashboard', array('as' => 'administrator.dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));

get('/dashboard/index', array('as' => 'administrator.dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
```

Here is the composer of laravel 5

"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "APPPATH\": "app/"
    }
},

Does anyone knows why is not working? Thank you

The error message

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
>
> Class APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController does not exist in
>   Container.php line 776
>
> at
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController')
>   in Container.php line 776
>
> at Container->build('APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController',
>   array()) in Container.php line 656
>
> at Container->make('APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController',
>   array()) in Application.php line 620
>
> at Application->make('APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController')
>   in ControllerDispatcher.php line 83
>
> at
>   ControllerDispatcher->makeController('APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController')
>   in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request),
>   'APPPATH\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', 'index') in Route.php
>   line 198
>
> at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line
>   131
>
> at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
>
> at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   141
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   101
>
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
>
> at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in
>   Router.php line 660
>
> at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
>
> at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
>
> at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   141
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
>
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
>
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
>
> at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   StartSession.php line 61
>
> at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
>
> at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   EncryptCookies.php line 40
>
> at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
>
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   in Pipeline.php line 125
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   101
>
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
>
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
>   line 84
>
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53

Comment: It wasn't working because of this function $this->loadAndAuthorizeResource();

Answer (score 1):

Should be App, not APPPATH

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: because I'm using laravel 5 inside the composer I have the following 

 "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "database"
  ],
  "psr-4": {
   "APPPATH\\": "app/"
  }
 },

Comment: you should reinstall your laravel, it seems wrong to me

Answer (score 1):

For my case I was getting this error for some authentication issue. 
I get resolved the issue by following the simple 2 steps in L5.1 :

1. Put "league/oauth2-server": "4.1.*" on the require section of your composer.json file.
2. run 'composer update' command on terminal.

You can try also.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
get('/', array('as' => 'administrator.dashboard', 'uses' => '\APPPATH\Http\DashboardController@index'));
```

It will try to get it from root namespaces

Answer (score 0):

If your file exists in `App\Http\Controllers\Administrator\Dashboard\DashboardController.php`, then first your given namespace is incorrect and the second thing is in your routes.php you are sending it in `DashboardController` which assumes that it will present directly after the `controllers` directory. Try the below changes.

- In your `DashboardController.php`

  ```
  namespace APPPATH\Http\Controllers\Administrator\Dashboard;

  class DashboardController extends Controller {

  }
  ```
- In your `routes.php`, change your route as below

  ```
  get('/', array('as' => 'administrator.dashboard', 'uses' => 'Administrator\Dashboard\DashboardController@index'));
  ```

I hope this will work.